# Router Angular me carga 404 cuando lo despliego en firebase

Tags: angular, router, angular-router

llevo dias tratando de resolver este problema con el router de angular, lo que necesito es poder acceder a la ruta post:id cuando la comparta desde redes sociales, de modo que el usuario ingrese directamente al post, pero cuando comparto el link firebase me da un 404

he intentando colocar un # en la ruta pero aun asi no logro solucionar el problema.

he intentando usar un children pero tampoco me ha funcionado.

```
const routes: Routes =

[
  
{path:'',component:ContainerAppComponent,children:

[
{ path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./components/pages/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule) },
{path:'#post/:id',component:DetailsPostComponent},
{ path: 'about', loadChildren: () => import('./components/pages/about/about.module').then(m => m.AboutModule) },
{path:'',redirectTo:'',pathMatch:'full'}
]

},
{ path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => import('./components/admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule) },
{ path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import('./components/auth/login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule) },
{ path: 'stat', loadChildren: () => import('./components/posts/estadisticas/estadisticas.module').then(m => m.EstadisticasModule) },


]



@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Prueba desactivando todas las rutas, excepto la deseada. Ingresala manualmente en tu navegador. Retira `#` del inicio del path. No es necesario. Me comentas tus resultados.

Comment: No me funciona aun :( a que se debe esto? osea puedo acceder desde la pagina principal donde estan los demas post y entra, pero cuando quiero compartir el link de un post en especifico y trato de ingresar sigue con el 404.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Enrutador de angular 10 no puedo compartir el link de una ruta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/390001/enrutador-de-angular-10-no-puedo-compartir-el-link-de-una-ruta)

Comment: Por favor, no repitas la misma pregunta dos veces